# How to get data from server and populate SQL database on Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to download data from the Firebase Firestore (array of names) and create the SQL table and feed the table with the data from the server. And every time I launch the app, I check version number from firebase, if it is the same as the SQL database version, and if it's not I recreate the table and populate it with new data.

Problem is I did something wrong with creating and checking the version number, so I get

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 5 to 4.

This exception is pretty straightforward but I do not know where I messed up.

This is my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class

```
public class SQLBazaNamirnica extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String Ime_Baze = "baza_namirnica";
    private static final String IME_TABELE = "tabela_namirnica";
    private static final String ID_KOLONA = "id";
    private static final String NAMIRNICA_KOLONA = "namirnica";
    private static int VERZIJA_BAZE = 4;

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    Context context;

    public SQLBazaNamirnica(Context context) {
        super(context, Ime_Baze, null, VERZIJA_BAZE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        this.db = sqLiteDatabase;

        String kreirajTabelu = "CREATE TABLE " + IME_TABELE +
                " (" + ID_KOLONA + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                NAMIRNICA_KOLONA + " TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(kreirajTabelu);

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int staraV, int novaV) {

        if(staraV != novaV)
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + IME_TABELE);

    }

    boolean CheckVerziju(int novaVer) {

        //db = getWritableDatabase();

        SQLiteDatabase _db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Log.d("SQL VERZIJA", "CheckVerziju: VERZIJA BAZE: " + _db.getVersion() + " \n VERZIJA FIREBASE BAZE: " + novaVer);

        if(_db.getVersion() != novaVer) {
            //VERZIJA_BAZE = novaVer;
            _db.setVersion(novaVer);
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

    void KreirajTabelu() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + IME_TABELE);


        String kreirajTabelu = "CREATE TABLE " + IME_TABELE +
                " (" + ID_KOLONA + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                 NAMIRNICA_KOLONA + " TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(kreirajTabelu);

        Log.d("SQL", "KreirajTabelu: BAZA JE KREIRANA");
    }

    void updateBazu(SQLiteDatabase db, ArrayList<String> namirnice) {

        db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        for(String namirnica : namirnice) {
           /* String query = "INSERT INTO " + IME_TABELE + " (" +
                    NAMIRNICA_KOLONA + ") VALUES (" + namirnica + ")"; */

            cv.put(NAMIRNICA_KOLONA, namirnica);

            db.insert(IME_TABELE, null, cv);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm the checking version number :

```
bazaNamirnica = new SQLBazaNamirnica(MainActivity.this);

namirniceDokument.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

        if(documentSnapshot.exists()) {

            int verzijaBaze = documentSnapshot.getLong("verzija").intValue();

            if(bazaNamirnica.getReadableDatabase().getVersion() != verzijaBaze) {
                //bazaNamirnica.ve

                bazaNamirnica.KreirajTabelu();

                Map<String, Object> namirnice = documentSnapshot.getData();

                ArrayList<String> namirniceFinal = new ArrayList<>();

                for(Map.Entry<String, Object> namirnica : namirnice.entrySet()) {

                    namirniceFinal.add(namirnica.getValue().toString());


                }
                    bazaNamirnica.updateBazu(bazaNamirnica.getWritableDatabase(), namirniceFinal);
                    bazaNamirnica.getWritableDatabase().setVersion(verzijaBaze);

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should always consider checking if you have an updated version which is greater than your current version of the database. The `onUpgrade` function will only be called when there is an increase in the database version.

I am not sure what are the data that you are getting from the firebase database. However, I would like to suggest some changes to your code.

Instead of checking not equal, you might consider checking if the database version is greater like the following.

```
if (bazaNamirnica.getReadableDatabase().getVersion() < verzijaBaze) {
    // Do the upgrade operation. 
}
```

And also, I am not sure what you are trying to do on the version update. However, if you are dropping a table, you might need to create a new one with the updated structure that you need while upgrading your database.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int staraV, int novaV) {

    // if(staraV != novaV) // Not necessary, as this will be called on increase in the database version. 

   // So you have dropped the table here
   sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + IME_TABELE);

   // Should create a new one with the updated database schema that you got
   createDatabaseTableWithUpdatedSchema();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nope, It did not change anything.

How to change (increase) database verson?

Comment: I think VERZIJA_BAZE is the database version in your code.

Comment: Yes it is, but how and where I can change it to affect my database?

Comment: See the constructor of your class. It passes the version to the super class. So one way of updating is setting the variable mentioned above before creating your database open helper class.

Comment: And I think another way is using the `setVersion` function that you are already using.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, problem is that I get version number from Firestore (ver 6), check it with SQL version (ver 5), If versions do not match I set the version of the SQL database to version I got from Firestore (SQL = 6) and then database is recreated. 

But problem occcurs when I open activity again and try to create SQL object of my class, then that hardcoded version VERZIJA_BAZE is passed, but it is still 5, and DB version is somehow 6, and I think that is where problem occurs.

Comment: You are right. You might consider saving the updated database version in the `SharedPreferences` and read it from there instead of having a variable assigned to a static value.